# Corona Sdk Remove Ads IAP

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk

Hey guys can anyonr please help me out ? 
I need the syntax for remove ads IAP for corona sdk. I tried to implement it by my self but failed.
And also if possibile can you give me the code to show chartboost or vungle ad after game over.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a specific code for this. A lot depends on how you have your app implemented. But the basics are this:

1. Set a flag if you want to show ads or not:

   local showAds = true
2. Then in your code, wrap the ads.show() call with something like:

   if showAds then
       ads.show("banner") -- or interstital or however you call it.
   end
3. In your IAP code, when you detect a purchase and the purchase happens to be the purchase that turns off ads then do:

   showAds = false
4. You will need to save that information out and when you restart the app, read that value to determine what to initialize your app too.

Comment: Thank you rob. Can you give me a sample of it please

Comment: Not really. The sample is above. You have to adapt the logic to your own project.